# Why are optional properties in an object required for a ReadOnly object?

Tags: flowtype

Here's my example code:

```
/* @flow */

type A = {
    var1 : number,
}

type B = $ReadOnly<{
    var1 : number,
    var2? : string,
}>

let v : A = { var1: 1 };
let w : B =  v;
```

And the flow error:

```
    13: let w : B =  v;
                     ^ Cannot assign `v` to `w` because property `var2` is missing in `A` [1] but exists in object type [2].
        References:
        12: let v : A = { var1: 1 };
                    ^ [1]
        13: let w : B =  v;
                    ^ [2]
```

I understand that normally A cannot be casted as a B, because that would allow v.var2 to be assigned.  My thought would that making B ReadOnly would prevent that case.  So I'm not understanding the case at which this cast would be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that

```
type A = {
    var1: number,
};
```

means defines `A` as an object with a property `var1` being a `number` and all other properties being **unknown**.

For example:

```
type A = {
    var1: number,
};
type C = {
    var1: number,
    var2: boolean,
};

let c: C = { var1: 1, var2: true };
let a: A = c;
```

is valid, because the `A` type is compatible with `C`.

However, if we then added on a snippet like your code:

```
type B = {
    var1: number,
    var2?: string,
};
let b: B = a;
```

this would treat `b.var2` as `string|void` when it is in fact a `boolean` because `b === c`.